# Enable Android Studio spell checking on language specific strings.xml files

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio, spellchecking seems to be disabled for language specific strings.xml files (and I understand why it would be disabled by default).

But is it possible to enable it, to check values, for a couple of those files? ("fr/strings.xml" for example), or at least run it on demand.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid or to enforce spellchecking you could add `tools:locale` to the `<resources>` tag in your string xml.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:locale="en">
```

This tells Lint your resources' locale.

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20170910085312/http://alexsimo.com/mastering-tools-namespace-android/)

Comment: This does not enable spell checking on locale-specific resource files

Answer (score 0):

Yes, go to Android Studio Preferences > Editor > Inspections > Spelling > Typo (check the box). Also make sure all scopes have been selected.

Incorrect spellings in the strings file show up with a light green line, clicking on which would show a message that it may be a typo.

Comment: Yeah my bad, I was on the fr/strings.xml file when asked, it already works for the strings.xml but no the language specific files. I've edited my question

Comment: This is a good question. I couldn't find any functionality in Android Studio that lets you spell check a specific file with a specific language. Let me know if you solve this.