# How do I get typo warnings in locale-specific strings.xml according to my custom dictionaries in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, localization, android-resources, spell-checking

Same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42251944/enable-android-studio-spell-checking-on-language-specific-strings-xml-files), but I'll try to explain it better.

I want Android Studio to give me typo warnings according to my custom dictionaries. Typo inspections are enabled properly. I have already set up my project dictionary and `portuguese.dic` in settings, and spell checking works fine in code.

It also works in `values/strings.xml` (the default locale) but **it doesn't work in locale-specific xml resources**, like `values-pt/strings.xml`. It gives me warnings for common misspellings for `pt` language (which it detects automatically), but **I want the typo warnings that assume every word is wrong except for the ones present in my dictionaries**.

I have tried changing the `tools:locale` attribute to many values, but the problem remains: this affects only the "common misspellings", not typo spell-checking, which is disabled for the file no matter what I do.
I even tried disabling the Inspection for "common misspellings" (Android/Lint/Correctness/Messages/Spelling error) but it didn't work either.

Is this a bug in IDEA/Android Studio? It seems to be this way by design, but maybe there is a setting or something I'm missing.

Is there a way to enable this check, or some workaround to make it work?
Ideally this should just work in the editor, but if not possible, it would be fine to have at least a gradle script or something that I can run once to make sure everything is OK.

Comment: Looks like a known issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68796762.